# issue in drawing line using core graphics : bubbles are shown 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-graphics

Using core graphics , I am trying to draw a line, in that when I try to add shadow is creates lin and bubbles inside the line, see the image, I am not able to solve the issue. please find my code below

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2); 
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);

    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(-16.00, -5.0f), 5.0f);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    [super drawRect:rect];

    [curImage release];

}
```

Below is the `touchesMoved` method.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch  = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2  = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1  = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint    = [touch locationInView:self];

    // calculate mid point
    CGPoint mid1    = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2); 
    CGPoint mid2    = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
    CGPathRelease(path);

    CGRect drawBox = bounds;

    //Pad our values so the bounding box respects our line width
    drawBox.origin.x        -= self.lineWidth * 2;
    drawBox.origin.y        -= self.lineWidth * 2;
    drawBox.size.width      += self.lineWidth * 4;
    drawBox.size.height     += self.lineWidth * 4;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawBox.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [curImage retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:drawBox];

}

CGPoint midPoint(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)
{
    return CGPointMake((p1.x + p2.x) * 0.5, (p1.y + p2.y) * 0.5);
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    previousPoint2 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Here the issue arrives when I try to add the line

```
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(-16.00, -5.0f), 5.0f);
```

[image: Issue image]

Please help me out from the issue, thanks in advance.  please see editing question with methods .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear you are drawing a series of segments as quad curves. The bubbles would be where the previous segment and the current segment overlap. Since your segment line is a solid red, you don't notice the overlap, but it shows up in the shadows as darker regions.

Try setting your stroke color to have and alpha of 0.5 (or some such translucency). I think (know) you will see the overlapping segments will also show a similar effect as the the shadow.

To solve it, you will want to draw the segment as a continuous path for each line. I'm guessing you are using `touchesBegan:withEvent:` / `touchesMoved:withEvent` / `touchesEnded:withEvent:` to obtain the points of the lines?

In that case, when `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is called, start your new path. During `touchesMoved:withEvent` render the new path over the current image. Commit the path to a `UIImage` in `touchesEnded:withEvent:`. At this point you may discard the path until `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is called again with the next stroke.

**Update**

In your code snippets you end up rendering the whole view three times every run loop. That's a lot of drawing overhead. I quickly put together some code that demonstrates what I am talking about above. It is not tested code, but it should be mostly right:

**Update 2**

I had a bit of time to write and test some code that will do what you are seeking based on my latest two comments. This code is from the view controller instead of the view itself, but with a little modification, you can move in the view if you like. As such, I added an `UIImageView` as a subview to the generic `UIView` to hold and display the image (and maintained a reference to in the view controller), and made the view controller the first responder in order to receive the touch events. Lots of hard coded values that you can clean up when integrating into your own project:

```
static
UIImage *CreateImage( CGRect rect, NSArray *paths )
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 1.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat colorComponents[4] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, colorComponents);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    for ( id obj in paths ) {
        CGPathRef path = (CGPathRef)obj;
        CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    }    
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetShadow(context, (CGSize){-8.0,40}, 5.0);
    CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

    CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

static
CGPoint MidPoint( CGPoint pt1, CGPoint pt2 )
{
    return (CGPoint){(pt1.x+pt2.x)/2.0,(pt1.y+pt2.y)/2.0};
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(myPath, NULL, location.x, location.y);

    [self.paths addObject:(id)myPath];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint midPoint = MidPoint(previousLocation, location);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(myPath, NULL, midPoint.x, midPoint.y, location.x, location.y);

    self.imageView.image = CreateImage(self.view.bounds, self.paths);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint midPoint = MidPoint(previousLocation, location);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(myPath, NULL, midPoint.x, midPoint.y, location.x, location.y);

    self.imageView.image = CreateImage(self.view.bounds, self.paths);

    CGPathRelease(myPath);
    myPath = nil;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but I am not able to get to your point exactly. as this is being totally new topic for me.

Comment: Fair enough. As the user moves their finger creating the overall stroke, a series of points are recorded (one every run loop cycle). You apparently only record the previous and current point to record into your new `UIImage`. Instead, consolidate all the points generated between the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` message and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` message, convert them to a path (either a CGPath or an UIBezierPath) **after** the user has lifted their finger (`touchesEnded:withEvent:`), and commit the full stroke to your new `UIImage`. @relikd's comments about transparency layers is good too.

Comment: Thanks for the code help, your code is proper but it will create the drawing at the touch end, And I need to draw the line with user's movement of finger, So I am trying to change the code den let u know what is the result.

Comment: That is true. I inadvertently left out drawing during the stroke. Like I said, I didn't test this code, it was an example. Rendering the current path in drawRect: or as an intermediate UIImage during touchesBegan and touchesMoved would be trivial.

Comment: Truthfully, my code doesn't solve the shadow issue. In order to do that, you'll need to maintain a list of your paths and render them all to a new UIImage (throwing out the old) in the as I did with just the newest path in touchesEnded. Otherwise, you won't have the "bubbles", but you will still have shadows over top the strokes. That's what I get for not testing my code.

Comment: Thank you very much, with the updated answer my issue is totally resolved. Now I am trying to make the line smooth, that is not a big issue. once again thank you very much....

Comment: I need one more suggestion, when I try to change color of the line at that time the color of previous drawings is also changed , can you help me ? like currently I am using red color,  now if i change the color to Blue and then draw, the red color will also be changed to blue !!1

Comment: You will need to store the color with the path. Since you can't store the color directly in the path, you'll need to create an object (or dictionary) for each color/path pair and store them in the array instead of just the path itself. Bonus points if you create a class that has a drawInContext:rect: method to do the setting of the stroke color and drawing of the path.

Answer (score 4):

the problem is you have multiple lines which lie above each other. So the shadows of both overlap and you get a darker color.

For something that easy like your line drawings you can simply copy the whole drawing code and redraw with a different color and a view pixel offset (instead of the shadow). E.g. you save the curves into an array and draw them separately later.

EDIT:
ok @gschandler describes the problem great too.

But you may also like to have a look at the [Transparency Layer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_trans_layers/dq_trans_layers.html) documentation. Group the elements together and apply a shadow for the group.

Answer (score 2):

Another way round to this is to create an array of points on touch move events, and then draw them..

Create an array of points :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[pointArray release]; pointArray = nil;
pointArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
[bufferArray removeAllObjects];

previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
previousPoint2 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
[pointArray addObject: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:previousPoint2]];
[pointArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:previousPoint1]];   
[pointArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:currentPoint]];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   

}


-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);

CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(-16.00, -5.0f), 5.0f);

for(int i = 1 ; i < [pointArray count]-1;i++)
{
CGPoint mid1 = midPoint([pointArray objectAtIndex:i+1], [pointArray objectAtIndex:i]); 
CGPoint mid2 = midPoint([pointArray objectAtIndex:i+2], [pointArray objectAtIndex:i+1]);


CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
i+=2;
}
CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

You can manage multiple lines with multiple dimensional array :)

Comment: Hi Dimple, Thanks for the reply, but the code is getting crashed at for loop, the mid2 point, index value sounds to be having some logical issue. When I tried with debug, it got crashed at [pointArray objectAtIndex:i+2] as there was not object at that index ,please share how this part is working!!

Comment: please add i+=2 in loop, since we are using 4 points at a time, we need this.